# Unable to change working directory using shell_exec() in php

Tags: php, laravel, shell, command-line-interface

Iam working on my own php MVC. And now, I wanted to create a cli tool for starting a live server which can be used for development purposes. I'm using laravel-zero for building my cli. All the commands are working fine except the command that is supposed to start a server. To start my server, first I need to change my current working directory to public and then start a php server using '**php -S localhost:9000**'

I have tried the below code, but it doesn't work:

```
shell_exec("cd public");
shell_exec("php -S localhost:9000");
```

I have also tried this, but this too doesn't work:

```
shell_exec("cd public ; php -S localhost:9000");
```

Finally after lots of google searches, I tried this, but the same result:

```
chdir("public");
shell_exec("php -S localhost:9000");
```

All It shows is just '**The system cannot find the path specified.**'

Comment: Have you tried it with a full path i.e. `shell_exec(/home/USERNAME/command_to_execute);`

Comment: Can you specify the operating system? "The system cannot find the path specified.", looks like something from Windows. Maybe it's relevant.

Comment: @jnko that will not work, he will need to specify the folder of the command php. better use the flag `-t` to change to root folder of the serving

Comment: @Hendrik Yes i'm on Windows OS.

Comment: messages comes from  "cd public", so you cant change dir from where you are to public, do a echo shell_exec('cd'); to see where you are and use full path to public.

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory when running `shell_exec()` is your installation root directory, you can just add the path after php

```
shell_exec("php -S localhost:9000 -t public/");
```

But since you are using laravel, why dont you just run `php artisan serve`

Comment: I just wanted to know how "php artisan serve" works

Comment: @AshishToppo https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation at the bottom of installation section **[Serving Laravel]** section, you have all the details you need